# Improvement in code written using Java8 streams - traditional for loop

Tags: java

I am writing API code using SpringBoot, Spring JDBC Template etc. In one scenario, I am fetching list of Object from DB and storing it like this:

```
List<StudentDataVO> studentData = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<StudentDataVO>(StudentDataVO.class), params);
```

Querying is working absolutely fine and studentData value is getting populated correctly.

**StudentDataVO** is a pojo class with getters and setters:

```
public class StudentDataVO 
{

    private List<BigDecimal> studentIDList = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();

    private List<String> studentNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private List<StudentItemVO> studentDescList = new ArrayList<StudentItemVO>();
}
```

**StudentItemVO** is also a pojo class with getters and setters:

```
public class StudentItemVO 
{

    private BigDecimal key;

    private String value;

}
```

My next requirement is to use values from **studentIDList** and **studentNameList** Lists and populate it into **studentDescList**.
**Note**: There is one to one mapping between **studentIDList** and **studentNameList** Lists.

I have written below code as per my understanding using Java8 streams (I am passing studentData fetched via query to populateStudentDescList), but I am still feeling this code can be written in a better way with better code quality. Please suggest or help.

```
private void populateStudentDescList(List<StudentDataVO> studentData) {
        studentData.stream().forEach(s -> {
            if (Objects.nonNull(s.getStudentIDList()) && Objects.nonNull(s.getStudentNameList())) 
            {
                List<StudentItemVO> itemList = new ArrayList<StudentItemVO>();
                for (int i = 0; i < s.getStudentIDList().size(); i++) {
                    StudentItemVO item = new StudentItemVO();
                    item.setKey(s.getStudentIDList().get(i));
                    item.setValue(s.getStudentNameList().get(i));
                    itemList.add(item);
                    s.setStudentDescList(itemList);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Personally, I will not prefer mentioning List in the variable names if its already a list,

   Example: `studentIDList`
2. `populateStudentDescList`: Good use of the `stream`, but we can also filter the non null objects earlier,

3. Create parameterised constructor for StudentItemVO,

```
class StudentItemVO
{

  private BigDecimal key;

  private String value;

  public StudentItemVO(java.math.BigDecimal key, String value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
  }
...
```

4. For creating objects from both the list, I would use an `IntStream`. The final method will look like,

```
private void populateStudentDescList(List<StudentDataVO> studentData) {
    studentData.stream()
      .filter( s -> Objects.nonNull(s.getStudentIDList()) && Objects.nonNull(s.getStudentNameList()))
      .forEach( s -> {
        List<BigDecimal> studentIds = s.getStudentIDList();
        List<String> studentNames = s.getStudentNameList();
        List<StudentItemVO> descs = IntStream
                    .range(0, studentIds.size())
                    .mapToObj(i -> new StudentItemVO(studentIds.get(i), studentNames.get(i)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        s.setStudentDescList(descs);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Praveen for your detailed and accurate explanation. Kudos to your java8 knowledge and explanation skill. Thanks much !!!

Comment: My rule of thumb is that if a lambda does not fit in a one liner, it should go into a standalone class. If there is more than one line, it probably contains logic that needs to be unit tested and that is much easier with a standalone class.

Comment: Can you please share your thoughts via modifying the above code, so that we can relate better. @TorbenPutkonen